# Google maps can not resolve method getMap()

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am using google map in my project. it was working but i did something( dont know what)now getMap() gives error. i think i update something. how can i fix it?

my code is like that;

```
GoogleMap googleMap;
..
 if (locationManagerCheck.isLocationServiceAvailable()) {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            try {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();//ERROR
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }...
```

i tried make it:

```
  googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);
```

but 'this' gives another error
can you help me?

edit:

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


 LocationManager_check locationManagerCheck = new LocationManager_check(
                this);


        if (locationManagerCheck.isLocationServiceAvailable()) {
            if (googleMap == null) {
                try {
                    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
               {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // TODO: Consider calling
                        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                        //                                          int[] grantResults)
                        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                        return;
                    }
                    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                    googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onInfoWindowClick(final Marker marker) {....}



}

 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap Map) {
        googleMap=Map;
    }



}
```

Comment: You should use the getMapAsync method, but `this` has to be the implementation of  the interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give a look to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map)

To add a map to an activity, add map fragment to your layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And then use it in your activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

         map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
         map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInfoWindowClick(final Marker marker) {....}

}
```

The map will be created in async way, and the onMapReady function will be called when map is ready,in this function you will be able to add markers, change position, title, zoom or whatever.

Comment: this way i should change everything i want go back old google service version how can i do that

Comment: which google service version do you want to use and why ?

Comment: Because my code was working before i update google play services

Comment: i can't use getMap() function

Comment: you can use the map in onMapReady function, and play with it there.

Comment: can i use googleMap like that ;  @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap Map) {
        googleMap=Map;
    }

Comment: sure you can, but keep in mind that if you use it in other method you should test if googleMap is not null

Comment: when does onMapReady start?

Comment: Use the onMapReady(GoogleMap) callback method to get a handle to the GoogleMap object. The callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used. It provides a non-null instance of GoogleMap. You can use the GoogleMap object to set the view options for the map or add a marker, for example.

Comment: i tried use googleMap after  MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this); it gives nullpointerexception

Comment: googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);//THIS GIVES NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION

Answer (score 0):

At the point you're retrieving the map it is `null`. You need to do it when you now the views have been initialised.

For example, in a `Fragment` you could do it in `onViewCreated` or in an `Activity` in `onCreate` after calling `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);`

For example:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    MapView mapView = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

Comment: Yes i did like that.  But it was working then i did something wrong about dependencies i think

Comment: Would help if you post both errors you are receiving. I assumed they were `NullPointerExceptions`